# Can I pass an informative String inside an event launched by a firePropertyChange()?

Tags: java, swing, events

I have the following situation:

Inside a class I launch a **PropertyChange event** by the use of **firePropertyChange()** method, that that is caught and handled in another class, in this way:

```
if (authResponse.getStatusResponse() == 0) {
    firePropertyChange("loginResult", false, loginResult);
} else {
    errorLabel.setText(authResponse.getErrorMessage());
    errorLabel.setVisible(true);
}
```

Ok, so in my case I have:

```
firePropertyChange("loginResult", false, loginResult);
```

It work well and is correctly intercepted in the other class but I have some doubts on the meaning of the previous code and I have to implement a new behavior.

1) What exactly represents the 3 parameter inside the **firePropertyChange()** method?

I think that they are:

**loginResult**: the property name (the property that is changed).
**false**: is the old value (in my specific case it means that the user was not logged).
**loginResult**: it is become true if the user is now logged in.

Is it my reasoning true?

And now I have the following problem: When I perform the **firePropertyChange()** method I am launching an object event that contains the previous 3 property (is it true?), the problem is that now I have also to pass another object (a String that represent the username of the logged user). Can I put it into the event object in some way?

Comment: _What exactly represents the 3 parameter inside the firePropertyChange()_ how about reading the api doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) What exactly represents the 3 parameter inside the firePropertyChange() method?

- name, the name of the property. This is typically the name of the getter and setter ie. `enabled` would typically be triggered by using `setEnabled` and retrieved by `isEnabled`
- oldValue, the old value, before it was changed
- newValue, the new value that it has been changed to

> And now I have the following problem: When I perform the
>   firePropertyChange() method I am launching an object event that
>   contains the previous 3 property (is it true?),

Yes, you are triggering a `propertyChanged` event which will be passed to all registered listeners, this will be encapsulated within a `PropertyChangeEvent` object

> the problem is that now I have also to pass another object (a String
>   that represent the username of the logged user). Can I put it into the
>   event object in some way?

No you can't (or could, but shouldn't), this is not what this event is for.  This event is designed to provide information about state change within the object, not provide secondary information about that state change (like what caused it)...

Instead, you could either...

As for more information from the source of the event.  This does assume you know the type of object that caused the event.

Or...

Create your own, custom listener, which provide the information required.

For example, you could create a `AuthenticationListener` that had `authenticationFailed` and `authenticationSucceeded` events.

You could then create a `AuthenticationEvent` which carried the information you needed to these event methods

Comment: Tnx so much, can I do the following thing? The PropertyChangeEvent is something like this: PropertyChangeEvent(Object source, String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue), so the oldValue and the newValue are generic object (and not only boolean value), in the previous example I pass simple boolean value as oldValue and newValue, if instead it I pass a custom object that contains inside it the boolean outcome and another String field for the username...could be a solution?

Comment: Stop trying to make your car fly. The `PropertyChange` event API has a particular job to do. Rather than trying to put a horse in a dog house, build a barn...it's early, so for the analogies